# Time as a Spiral

Tags: sources-mekorot, calendar, time, breslov

@PixelArtDragon [asked](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/concept-that-time-is-a-spiral) what rabbi originated the idea that time is a spiral. @PixelArtDragon said that the earliest they've found is Rav Natan Breslov who lived from 1780-1844 - can anyone locate that Rav Natan source? I was unable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concept that time is a spiral](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/concept-that-time-is-a-spiral)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @DonielF I don't think it's a duplicate. The question you link to asks about the concept itself. This question is asking for a source to a claim made in that question. Maybe this question should be edited to better reflect that.

Comment: @DonielF That question asking for earlier sources than Nathan of Breslov is the basis of this distinct question asking for the actual specific text of Nathan of Breslov.

Comment: @TamirEvan You’re only pinged if you’ve participated in the comment thread so that won’t help either.